# collection not populating in many to many relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In a spring mvc app, I have a many to many relationship between a `Caregiver` entity and a `Patient` entity.  The jsp view that creates a new `caregiver` is not adding the specified `patient` to the `patients` collection that is associated with the `caregiver` instance.  You can see this in the following printscreen of the controller code, which is being run in debug mode and has stopped at the line below the point where the `patient` should have been added to the `caregiver`'s collection of `patients`:

[image]

Similarly, the next printscreen below shows the debugger indicating that the `patients` collection is empty for the given `caregiver`, at the point in the controller's execution indicated above, where the `patient` should have been added to the `caregiver`:

[image]

Queries in the underlying mysql database show that the `caregiver` has been added to the `caregiver` table, but that there is no record in the join table that should link the `caregiver` with the specified `patient`.  Why is the `patient` not added to the `caregiver`?

If I write `patient.addCaregiver(caregiver)` or `caregiver.addPatient(patient)` in that part of the code, the result is a stack overflow error with endless repetitive adding of `caregiver` and `patient` to each other, indicating that adding manually is apparently unnecessary.  So how do I make sure the `patient` gets added?

For reference, I have added the full code of the `Caregiver` entity and the `Patient` entity to a file sharing site, which you can access by clicking the following links:

[Click here](https://jumpshare.com/v/3HAqkYZj1dJ74P2muhJQ?b=jbaQaDtHdFhkuzySXiuB) to view the code for the `Caregiver` entity.
You can view the code for the `Patient` entity [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/ckCKWuvAaDdFF6iDUmuK?b=3w1KOzCMlGIbg0n7h4y8).

---

EDIT:

---

Following Kresimir's advice, I altered the Patient.addCaregiver() method as follows:

```
public void addCaregiver(Caregiver c) {getCaregiversInternal().add(c);}
```

I also modified the Caregiver.addPatient() method to be:

```
public void addPatient(Patient p) {getPatientsInternal().add(p);}
```

Note that getCaregiversInternal() and getPatientsInternal() return the caregivers and patients collections, respectively, as shown in the code at the file sharing site in the links above.

New caregivers are still not associated to the respective patient's collection.  How specifically do I change these or other methods to make this happen?

Comment: I posted an answer but it seems I misunderstood your question. Is your problem that the caregiver.patients collection is not populated correctly by the controller or is the problem with hibernate not storing the collection correctly to the database? My answer pertains to the latter. If it's the former, where are you adding the caregiver to the patient?

Comment: @KresimirNesek The problem is that, when the user creates a new caregiver record, the caregiver is not being added to the specified patient's collection of caregivers.  I am more concerned with patient.caregivers.  The main jsp for a patient links to this jsp which creates a caregiver and then goes back to the main jsp for the patient.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the mapping, `Patient` is the entity that owns the `Patient` - `Caregiver` relationship. This can be deduced from the fact `inverseJoinColumn` points to `caregiver_id`.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="careTeamJunction",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="patient_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="caregiver_id")}) //patient owns relationship
private Set<Caregiver> caregivers = new HashSet<Caregiver>();
```

Since `Patient` is the entity that owns the relationship, it should be enough to add `Caregiver` to `Patient` object's `caregivers` set and hibernate should store the relationship in the join table.

Also, there is a problem with addPatient and addCaregiver methods - they call each other creating an endless recursion. Modify patient.addCaregiver to add caregiver to patient's caregiver set but do not call caregiver.addPatient also to avoid recursion (alternatively in caregiver.addPatient remove call to patient.addCaregiver).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write an answer.  I am testing this now.  I will reply soon.

Comment: I posted an edit to my original posting above showing changes I made to Patient.addCaregiver() and to Caregiver.addPatient().  New caregivers are still not being added to the selected patient's caregivers collection.  What can I do to fix this?